# Doubts on some Rules to be followed for Google material design

Tags: javascript, material-design, dpi

I'm trying to use material design concept for web app. In Google docs they have mentioned some spacing rules in dp.

[image]

Measurements in the above image are in dp and sp.
([Check here](https://material.google.com/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-labels)) scroll down in that docs till specs section for field and label spacing measurements. To follow these measurements I cant figure out how to calculate px value from dp. The dp formula as mentioned in google docs is

```
dp = (width in pixels * 160) /  screen density
```

[For formula](https://material.google.com/layout/units-measurements.html#units-measurements-density-independent-pixels-dp-)

To use this formula I need Screen density. 
So Here is the question.

**How do you calculate screen density from your web application?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Material Design Guildelines](https://material.google.com/layout/units-measurements.html#units-measurements-density-independent-pixels-dp-):

> When writing CSS, use px wherever dp or sp is stated. Dp only needs to be used in developing for Android.

That means: You don't need to find out the screen density (which won't be easy to do anyway).